# International accents out of dead keys in Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, keyboard-layout, dead-keys

From the first moment, after the installation of Lubuntu 12.04, I cannot type Greek accents, when the Greek layout is selected.

The Greek layout works with some dead keys, i.e. pressing `;`+ `α` gives accented `α` etc. In my case the dead key is ignored and `α` remains without an accent.

I have looked all similar questions in askubuntu or forums, but they do not seem to provide a solution to the exact problem for Greek.

Answer (score 0):

http://po-ru.com/diary/lubuntu-1210-problems-and-solutions/

solved the problem in my case.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.